# Why did app engine perform writer operation when I "read" HttpSession Attribute

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets

the write operation on the httpsession is consuming my resources

I have a on UserSession attribute in the session which only store a userID and hash

write operation should only perform while login

but each time I use UserSession in my controller datastore_v3.Put was performed

what is happening???

I am using spring mvc in my project

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the session state is being saved because Spring MVC has no way of knowing if the state of the session-scoped objects has been changed during the request.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably updating the timestamp of your session to keep it fresh on every access.

If you're really curious, you can get to the low-level session data using (I *believe*) the _AH_SESSION table (do a query on table Query.KIND_METADATA_KIND in empty ns for the full list of tables, including "hidden" tables).